# rsync in a FreeBSD jail: failed to set times: Operation not permitted

Tags: rsync, freebsd, zfs, jail

I have a single "partition" ZFS pool mounted to a directory inside /jails/www/usr/local/www/stuff (that is served by nginx) and from inside that jail I have chown'd that directory to a particular user. I have rsync periodically updating that directory from a remote server. Files are syncing fine, however there is a persistent error:

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/usr/local/www/stuff/file": Operation not permitted
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't aware that chown doesn't touch symlinks themselves by default. Doing `chown -hR /usr/local/www/stuff` solved it.